# Prove the following function isn't uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

I need to prove the function

> $f(x)=x\ln(x)$

is not uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,\infty)$
I have tried using some theorems about uniform continuity but non of which apply in this case.

Any help is much appreciated.

~Yuval

Comment: equicontinuous is not the word you want

Comment: @Bernard8 How so? that's precisely the question I need to solve just translated to English :P

Comment: equicontinuity is a property that can be held by a collection of functions (definitely more than one). Your question only refers to an individual function.

Comment: @Bernard8 In my book, equicontinuity of a single function is defined to be:

$f(x)$ is equicontinuous if and only if $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, |x_1-x_2|<\delta\implies |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\varepsilon$

Comment: Ah, that's uniform continuity

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't know. Fixed.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111006/show-fx-x-ln-x-is-not-uniformly-continuous).