# Show that $x\ln(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I am trying to show that $f(x) = x\ln(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,\infty)$. The solution given here [Show $f(x)=x\ln x$ is not uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111006/show-fx-x-ln-x-is-not-uniformly-continuous)  does it by using $\epsilon-\delta$ but I want to do it by sequences if possible. The "x" term is messing things up because I cannot take $$x_n = \textrm e^{-n } $$ and $$y_n = \textrm e^{-n + 1}$$ because $|f(x) -f(y)|$ does not work out. Any ideas on sequences I can take?

Comment: With those $x_n$ and $y_n$ you are going in the wrong direction: $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$. You want sequences going off to $\infty$.

Comment: Ohhhhh, so you look for sequences around where the derivative explodes right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $x_n = e^{n^2}$ and $y_n = x_n + 1/n$. Note that $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$.

By the MVT there exists $\xi_n \in (x_n ,x_n + 1/n)$ such that

$$y_n \ln y_n - x_n \ln x_n = (1 + \ln \xi_n)/n > (1+\ln x_n)/n > n \to +\infty$$

**More generally**

A differentiable function $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is not uniformly continuous if $|f'(x)| \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. (It is not enough for $f'$ to be unbounded.)

For any $\delta > 0$ take $x \in (0,\infty)$ and $y = x + \delta/2$.  We have $|x-y| < \delta$, but there exists $\xi \in (x,y)$ such that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\xi)||y-x| = |f'(\xi)|\delta/2$$  If $|f'(x)| \to +\infty$ then there exists $X$ such that for all $\xi > x  > X$ we have $|f'(\xi)| > 2/\delta$ and, hence $|f(x) - f(y)| > 1$.

So for any $\delta > 0$ there exists $x,y \in (0,\infty)$ with $|x - y| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y) > 1$, and $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: The question here is about the uniform continuity of a function on an infinite interval , that happens to have a derivative where $f'(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.  Such a function can't be uniformly continuous.  I'm simply (1) using this to construct the sequences OP requested, and (2) explaining the underlying principle.  There are UC functions on $(0,\infty)$ with unbounded derivatives and UC functions on $[0,1]$ like $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ where $f'(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$   The principle I am using only pertains to the case where $|f'(x)| \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @bof:  Yes if $f$ is UC on $[1,\infty)$, then $|f(x)| = \mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.  There are many ways to answer this question.  I just took one approach. Although unless you already know the $\mathcal{O}(x)$ result it is not as easy to prove as the derivative result if you are starting from first principles.

Comment: thanks for the response!! @RRL , so in a general function that has a derivative that goes to infinity as x goes to infinity cant be uniformly continuous?

Comment: @Matt:  Yes. If the derivative is bounded then it's uniformly continuous like $f(x) =x$. If the limit of the derivative as $x \to \infty$ is $\pm \infty$ then it's not uniformly continuous like $f(x) = x^2$.  If it oscillates with no limit but is unbounded it may or may not be uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=n$ and $y_n=n+\frac 1 {\log n}$. Note that $\bigl(n+\frac 1 {\log n}\bigr) \log \bigl(n+\frac 1 {\log n}\bigr)-n \log n \geq \frac 1 {\log n} (\log n) \geq 1$.